# How to remove the "Done" bar above the iOS keyboard in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, safari

[image: iOS keyboard]

Is it possible to hide the `^ v    Done` bar from HTML webpage in iOS Safari?

```html
<form>
  <input type="search" />
</form>
```

Comment: I  also wish this were possible but I haven't seen  evidence it is. To the contrary, consider that the Google Maps iOS app has no "done" bar above the keyboard (which [seems possible for native apps](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-remove-done-button-upon-the-keyboard/17757)), but visit maps.google.com in iOS Safari and you will see a 'Done' bar when using the map search input. (So if Google Maps' web engineers can't  figure it out, it may not be possible.)

Comment: That said, if you want to remove Done to save space and you are presenting a drop down to select from, you may not need the autocomplete row (visible in the screenshot  above, between the keyboard and the 'Done' row). In the web,  that can be removed via `autocomplete="off"`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#values

Comment: Good point for the `autocomplete="off"`, thank you